# Python challenge 25: Writing files

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

**Python Challenge 25**

Write a sign-up program for an after-school club; it should ask the user for the following details and store them in a file:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Gender
- Form

For the above task I wrote the following python code:

```
# Python Challenge 25

print ("Hello user, this is a virtual application form"
       "\nfor joining after-school clubs at -Insert school name here-")

first_name = input("\n\nPlease input your first name:")
last_name = input("Please input your last name:")
gender = input("Please input your gender:")
form = input("Please input your form name:")
club = input("What after-school club would you like to attend?\n")

file = open("application-form.txt", "w")
file.write(first_name)
file.write (last_name)
file.write (gender) 
file.write (form)
file.write (club)
file.close()


print (first_name, "Thank you for taking your time to fill this virtual form"
       "\nall the information has been stored in a file to maintain confidentiality")
```

An example of the outcome of the above code:

[image]

**My question**

1. When the text file is saved all the user inputs is stored in one line, is there a way where I can put each input on a separate line?
2. Is there a more efficient way to write the above code?

Comment: By more efficient, do you mean shorter code, or runs faster?

Comment: a shorter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to `print`, `write` doesn't automatically append end of lines. You can add `file.write("\n")` between your writes to intercalate ends of line.

Alternatively, you can create a single string interspersing the end of lines, using `join`, and write that single string.

Example:

```
file.write("\n".join([line1, line2, line3]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Your code has solved the problem I was facing Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1) Replace `file.write(first_name)` with `file.write(first_name + '\n')` or add the line `file.write('\n')` just after.

2) I don't think the code can be made to run faster, and I don't think it needs to, but in terms of code quality/length I would write the file writing section like this:

```
with open("application-form.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in [first_name, last_name, gender, form, club]:
        f.write(first_name + '\n)
```

Comment: @ Alex Hall Thank you for your assistance. The above code has helped!

Answer (score 0):

As for making the code more efficient/neater, you could use a function to request and store the data:

```
def get_info(prompts):
    file = open("application-form.txt", "w")
    for prompt in prompts:
        file.write(input(prompt))
        file.write('\n')


print ("Hello user, this is a virtual application form"
       "\nfor joining after-school clubs at -Insert school name here-")

prompts = ["\n\nPlease input your first name:",
           "Please input your last name:",
           "Please input your gender:",
           "Please input your form name:",
           "What after-school club would you like to attend?\n"]

get_info(prompts)


print ("Thank you for taking your time to fill this virtual form"
       "\nall the information has been stored in a file to maintain confidentiality")
```

Unfortunately to do this I had to take out the `first_name` call in the thank you (last print statement).  If you absolutely need that you're probably better off with what you have so far.

Comment: The code looks more presentable now. Thank you for your help.